# How to convert positive inserted values into negative after update or insert?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I want to write a trigger which should find if the inserted or updated value is positive and replace it with negative. 
I tried this code:

```
create trigger trigger_after_updaten on Inbox
AFTER Update 
AS
begin
DECLARE @t INT 
If ((SELECT @t=ID_In FROM updated)>0) 
UPDATE Inbox SET t=@t*-1
END
```

but it show this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure trigger_after_updaten, Line 223
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

How to do it the right way?

Comment: Incorrect trigger definition. Always consider that inserted table has several rows. And SQL Server doesn't have an updated table, just "inserted" and "deleted".

Comment: An alternative solution would be to add a CHECK CONSTRAINT to the column, limiting the accepted values (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176104.aspx).

Comment: I'd second destination's suggestion - it's far better to have the DB reject incorrect data than to silently "fix" it. Silent fixes can be forgotten about and then produce extraordinarily confusing debugging experiences later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_after_updaten on Inbox
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Inbox SET t = CASE WHEN(inserted.t < 0) THEN inserted.t ELSE -inserted.t END
    FROM inserted
    INNER JOIN Inbox 
        ON inserted.KEY_FIELD = Inbox.KEY_FIELD
END
```

Comment: but this code doesn't examine if the updated value is negative or positive, I want to convert only positive values.

Comment: It examines this condition using case (I have updated post in a minute after posting)

Comment: It would be better to use the table's PK in the `ON` clause rather than the `t` value again. If you have an insert for, say, `-1`, then this query will (pointlessly) update all existing entries in the table which are currently equal to `-1`.

Comment: Thank you but it still give this error do you have an idea why?
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trigger_after_updaten, Line 235
Invalid object name 'updated'.

Comment: There is no "updated" table in SQL Server. Only "inserted" and "deleted". In this answer's script "inserted" table is used. It contains new values produced by UPDATE.

Comment: oh I forgot to delete my first trigger, It works thanks.